# Django LDAP / Как добавлять пользователей LDAP из админ панели?

Tags: django, django-admin

Может быть, кто-нибудь знает. Мне нужно добавить пользователя LDAP внутри админ-панели.
Моя аутентификация LDAP в Django работает, но я должен добавлять пользователей очень странно. Сначала они входят в систему, и они не попадают. Затем я захожу в админ-панель и вижу, что пользователь добавлен, но без флага Staff status. Я активирую флаг. Пользователь может войти под своей учетной записью LDAP.
Вопрос: можно ли сначала добавить пользователя LDAP в самой панели администратора и активировать все, что нужно, чтобы пользователю не приходилось входить дважды?
Setting.py:

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://X.X.X.X:389"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "CN=CN,OU=OU,DC=domain,DC=local"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "pass"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("OU=OU,DC=domain,DC=local",
        ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)"
)
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=local",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=group)"
)
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType()

AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {
        ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL: 0,
        ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: 0,
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend",
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
]

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail"
}
AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_GROUPS = True
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600
```

Comment: Не мешало бы представить Ваши исходники, которые подключают LDAP авторизацию.

Comment: Представил в посте

Comment: Енто читали? https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/permissions.html#group-mirroring

Comment: И почему кстати именно staff должно быть у пользователя? Ковырять сразу django админку чтоли?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, Да, про групповое зеркалирование в курсе, но нет возможности создать группу в AD для пользователей  Django. Неужели нельзя как то подтянуть базу пользователей LDAP в админ панель, чтоб просто выбирать тех, кто может иметь доступ?

Comment: я думаю можно. Как минимум через middleware.

Comment: А можете поподробнее или хоть ссылку на какой ресурс, чтоб поглядеть способы реализации?

Comment: Неужели никто не делал добавление LDAP юзеров через админку?

Comment: может кто подскажет админку по этому поводу какую-нибудь?